# NSolve two unknowns $ r, x $ in order to have a curve $ r(x) $

Tags: equation-solving, functions

I'm trying to solve :

```
 NSolve[3 r Sqrt[x/(1 - x)] + 1/2 r^3 (x/(1 - x))^(3/2) - (
 3 r x Csch[r Sqrt[x/(1 - x)]])/(1 - x) == 0, {x, 0.5, 1}, {r, 0, 
 5}]
```

My goal is to have a relation r(x), with r in [0,5] and x in [0.5,1]
But it looks like I'm not writing the command well because I'm getting the error:

> NSolve: 0.5` is not a valid variable.

How I can achieve what I want plz ?

Comment: You do not have to get the curve by solving it: `ContourPlot[
 3 r Sqrt[x/(1 - x)] + 1/2 r^3 (x/(1 - x))^(3/2) - (
   3 r x Csch[r Sqrt[x/(1 - x)]])/(1 - x) == 0, {x, 0.5, 1}, {r, 0, 
  1}]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been mentioned, one can get the curve by `ContourPlot`

```
f[x_, r_] := 3 r Sqrt[x/(1 - x)] + 1/2 r^3 (x/(1 - x))^(3/2) - (3 r x Csch[r Sqrt[x/(1 - x)]])/(1 - x)
plotOptions = Sequence[AspectRatio -> Automatic, FrameLabel -> {"x", "r"}, PlotTheme -> {"Scientific", "LargeLabels"}];

ContourPlot[f[x, r] == 0, {x, 0.5, .999}, {r, 0, 1}, PlotPoints -> 100, Evaluate[plotOptions]]
```

> [image]

---

Well, one also can solve it, numerically

```
rRoot[x_] := NSolve[f[x, r] == 0, r, Reals][[1, 1]]
data = rRoot~ParallelMap~Subdivide[.5, .999, 400] // Values;

ListLinePlot[data, DataRange -> {0.5, .999}, PlotRange -> {0, .9}, plotOptions]
```

> [image]

Answer (score 3):

I've answered this type question before (for instance, [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/185552/4999) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/186402/4999)), as follows:

```
rFN = NDSolveValue[{3 r Sqrt[x/(1 - x)] + 
       1/2 r^3 (x/(1 - x))^(3/2) - 
       (3 r x Csch[r Sqrt[x/(1 - x)]])/(1 - x) == 0 /. r -> r[x],
    t'[x] == 1, t[0.5] == 0.5}, r, {x, 0.5, 1}];

ListLinePlot@rFN
```

[image]

I ignore the error message at `x == 1`, which should be expected.

Of course if the function is not wanted and only a plot is desired, @Αλέξανδρος Ζεγγ has pointed out `ContourPlot`, which is easily found in the documentation.

Comment: Thx ! Looks amazing, but I quite don't understand what's going on : are you making Mathematica believe you want to solve an DE in t[x], and ask him eventually to give you r ?

Comment: @J.A Yes, adding the DE makes it into a DAE (differential-algebra equation).  `NDSolve` uses `FindRoot` to construct a table of values for `r[x]`, which gets returned in an `InterpolatingFunction`.  You need the `t'[x]` DE to trick it into constructing `r[x]`. Another approach would be to differentiate the equation and reintegrate with `NDSolve`.  See for example, [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/163012/4999).

Comment: @Michael E2 Nice idea!!! Believing that I got it I tried to test `Y = NDSolveValue[{x^2 + y[x]^2 == 1, Derivative[1][t][x] == 1, 
   t[-1] == -1}, y, {x, -1, 1}],
Plot[Y[u], {u, -1, 1}]` but failed in finding the circle. What's wrong? Thanks.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Because you start the integration where the circle defined by `y[x]` is singular.  Try `Y = NDSolveValue[{x^2 + y[x]^2 == 1, t'[x] == 1, t[0] == 0}, 
  y, {x, -1, 1}]`

Comment: @Michael E2 Thanks,it works! What means "singular" in this case? `y'->Infinity `?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Yes, `y' -> Infinity`. It's sometimes called a weak singularity. But it's probably better to think in terms of the inverse function theorem, so that when solving $F(x,y)=0$, $y'$ is undefined if $\partial F/\parital y = 0$. It's not necessary that $y' \rightarrow \infty$. For instance, the lemniscate `NDSolveValue[{(x^2 + y[x]^2)^2 == x^2 - y[x]^2, t'[x] == 1, t[0] == 0}, y, {x, -1, 1}]` fails. It also fails if the IC is at $x =\pm1$, but succeeds if integration is started sufficiently far from $-1, 0, 1$  but within $-1<x<1$.

Answer (score 1):

Try to solve them numerically using `FindRoot`. You may do it as follows.Here is your equation:

```
eq = 3 r Sqrt[x/(1 - x)] + 
   1/2 r^3 (x/(1 - x))^(3/2) - (3 r x Csch[r Sqrt[x/(1 - x)]])/(1 - 
      x) == 0
```

This is the numerical solution returning the nested list with the element `{x,r}` , where  `r` is the solution corresponding to this `x` vaue:

```
lst = Table[{x, 
    FindRoot[
      3 r Sqrt[x/(1 - x)] + 
        1/2 r^3 (x/(1 - x))^(3/2) - (3 r x Csch[
            r Sqrt[x/(1 - x)]])/(1 - x) == 0, {r, 1}][[1, 2]]}, {x, 
    0.5, 0.9, 0.01}];
```

Now, plotting it yields

```
    ListPlot[lst, 
 AxesLabel -> {Style["x", 16, Italic], Style["r", 16, Italic]}]
```

[image]

That's it. I did not check, if the solution is single, ot there are several. It is up to you. If this is the case, play with the initial guess for the `FindRoot` to reveal other solutions.

Have fun!